# Nagios to automatically send Google Authentication verification code

Tags: nagios

At the moment, my workplace's Nagios server is configured to SSH into host machines and then execute bash scripts on those host machines.

The customer now requires us to setup MFA for SSH sessions. I have successfully tested MFA using Google Authenticator by following this article: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-one-time-passwords-for-two-factor-authentication-with-ssh-on-centos/.

With MFA setup though, it will mean our Nagios server can no longer SSH into the host machines. I am wondering is there a way to configure the Nagios server to send verification codes automatically?

Comment: Why are you using SSH for Nagios executions? The standard setup would include an NRPE daemon on the monitored node. Combining automatic and headless SSH access with MFA is if not impossible, completely bypassing the point of having MFA in the first place.

Comment: It was already configured that way. I am looking into NRPE/NCPA as an option now.